# Magento List Products based by attribute in CMS page, how to?

Tags: magento, attributes

how can I list only porducts with some attribute on CMS page?

For example I want to list only all the products across the categories with attribute color=red
How can I achive this?

So far I was able to achive listing products with Special prices based on this
http://phpmysqltalk.com/937-magento-how-to-create-a-special-price-page-with-new-products-first.html

HoweverI am unable to modify it to any other attribute. Any help, how can I achieve displaying only products which have specific value of some attribute /from the Root category for the store or also from specific categories/

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

check out this tutorial for creating a simple custom module which should do exactly what you need:
https://www.atwix.com/magento/products-list-cms/